# Issue with <input type="number"> In Angular

Tags: html, angular, numbers, limit, digits

not taking long digits, after 17 or 18 th digit,the entered digits changes to zero
so My requirement is to limit the digits to 15, in a reusable way.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control"(keypress)="omit_special_char($event)"
```

```
omit_special_char(event,c?:any) {
           const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 45) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }`
```

Comment: You might be misusing the number input type, the HTML spec explains that it is “not appropriate for input that happens to only consist of numbers but isn't strictly speaking a number.” https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate. There are other attributes to control touch screen keyboards like inputmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `number` input type if you are not actually dealing with numbers:

> The `type=number` state is not appropriate for input that happens to only consist of numbers but isn't strictly speaking a number.

—[The HTML Standard on number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate)

The value of [`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#content) is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

When expressed in decimal, the `Number.MAX_VALUE` runs up to 16 digits, that’s why your code fails.

See also this question: [Why max digits with decimal in JavaScript are only 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800022/why-max-digits-with-decimal-in-javascript-are-only-16)

To solve this, use a more correct input type along with some indicators to provoke a touch keyboard optimised for numerics:

```html
<label>Something like a number, but not quite
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric">
</label>
```