# Can't resolve addition of 14 precision decimal number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I am stuck in a problem while dealing with large precision decimal numbers.
I basically have a number and I want to increase/decrease it by 1e-14 by user's prompt. But, I am stuck in the below mentioned two problems.

Prob.1

```
let val  = 1116.44599303135891;
let e = 1; 
let precision = 0;
while (Math.round(val * e) / e !== val) {
    console.log(Math.round(val*e)/e);
    e *= 10;
    precision++;
}
console.log(precision);
```

Here, I get precision = 12. But, the correct answer should have been 14.

Prob.2

```
65.85365853658558 + 1e-14 = 65.85365853658560
```

But, the correct answer should be `65.85365853658559`.

I am unable to figure it out as to why this is happening.

I know that the JS uses floating point numbers which are essentially 64 bits numbers. Can someone help me relate this information with the issue I have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800022/why-max-digits-with-decimal-in-javascript-are-only-16#:~:text=JS%20Number%20uses%20double%2Dprecision,bit%20precision%20(16%20digits).

Comment: There are a few libraries that will give you more precision ex. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal

Comment: this is not happening. every system have limits. JS engines are not usable for absolute math precision, this is not their purpose. This can't be happen, you must stop imagine that.